# Standard Regex syntax doesn't work in WordPress rewrite rule

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, regex

I've run into a regex issue while adding a rewrite rule into a Wordpress plugin.  This blog has been helpful and the redirect works correctly after following this: https://brightminded.com/blog/mastering-wordpress-rewrite-rules/

However, I'm facing a challenge on this section:
[image]

That's all fine, the redirect works perfectly.  But I want to change the regex in the rewrite rule so that  instead of matching `city/{anything}/` it instead matches 'city/?{anything}`.  And I'm running into an issue:

### The blog regex is invalid, yet it works

The regex in the blog is `^city/([^/]*)/?` and this works perfectly in the wordpress rewrite rule, however when I paste this into any online regex tool such as regex101.com or regexr.com, they say that the regex isn't valid:

[image]

### Valid regex expressions do not work

I can easily create a regex that works correctly such as: `^city\/\?.*` which matches to `city/?{anything}` just like I want.  However, this regex doesn't work in the Wordpress rewrite rule.  When I use this regex, and update permalinks in CMS, the redirect stops working.

So far, I can't find any documentation for using regex in Wordpress so I would presume it follows the de facto standard.  But please can anyone shed light on this?  Does wordpress use a different standard for Regex and where is the documentation for this?  Or is there a simple syntax error that I'm missing?

Comment: This isn't a regex problem, there's been a misunderstanding of what rewrite rules are rewriting and their purpose. `?` isn't a part of the URL path, it's the query/params, and it's used to specify GET variables, and the purpose of pretty permalinks aka rewrite rules, is to convert `/pretty/permalinks` into `index.php?foo=pretty&bar=permalinks`. So you can't use rewrite rules to create URLs like this `/pretty?permalinks` because only the `/pretty` part is a permalink. Remember rewrite rules are _not_ redirects, they map URL paths on to `index.php?queryvar=value` type URls, aka ugly permalinks

Comment: Furthermore, the regex _is_ valid, but you're attempting to use the default delimiter in the testing tool. The delimiter would have to be _something other_ than a `/` if you don't want to have to escape every other `/`.

Comment: Thanks both. @TomJNowell - That makes sense, so there's no way to confirm if a URL contains GET variables.  That's ok, I can handle that in the redirected page.

Comment: @vancoder - please can you help me more with this?  In the working example: `^city/([^/]*)/?` I'm actually not sure if the `/` is a delimiter or escape character or if it matches the literal character `/`  It looks like the example is completely unescaped, yet it works fine?